# cual es la mejor forma de representar los datos con while o sentencias especificas en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Hola amigos de Stackoverflow tengo una duda de cual es la mejor forma de presentar los datos en un index la verdad es que no se si lo ideal es traer los datos con un while o con sentencias especificas para ello muestro un ejemplo al respecto.

```
  //Con esta sentencia me muestra todos los estados que tengo actualmente
  $showdatos= "SELECT estado FROM estados_y_municipios ORDER BY estado ";

  $ver= mysqli_query($conn, $showdatos);

  while( $var =  mysqli_fetch_array($ver)) {
          echo $var['estado'] . "<br>";
  }
```

Pero si no uso el ciclo while solo muestra 1 solo estado lo cual tengo entendido si no es
que me equivoco es por que no hace un recorrido como lo hace while. En la terminal de mysql si muestra todos los estados si ejecuto la misma sentencia pero en php no :,v.

```
$showdatos= "SELECT estado FROM estados_y_municipios ORDER BY estado ";

$ver= mysqli_query($conn, $showdatos);
$var = mysqli_fetch_array($ver);
echo $var['estado'] . "<br>";
```

entonces me genera la duda si hacer simplemente un while o crear una consulta por estado como este ejemplo:

```
//Solo me traera el estado seleccionado
$showdatos= "SELECT estado FROM estados_y_municipios WHERE estado='Aguscalientes' ";
```

Es de buena practica realizarlo de esta forma? o lo mejor es traer todos los datos con un while? les agrazco sus comentarios y sugerencias gracias.

Comment: El sistema gestor de base de datos internamente realiza el recorrido por el conjunto de resultados y muestra todos los datos. Pero en el lado del servidor sí es necesario emplear un bucle para recorrer y mostrar los resultados. En el caso de que solo desees mostrar un resultado, entonces no será necesario el bucle.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo la verdad desconocia ese dato con MySQL :p  seria  ambas validas el uso de while en varios resultados y hacer una sentencia especifica en solo un resultado? es una buena practica?

Comment: Es simple: si tienes más de un resultado, usa un bucle. Si solo tienes un resultado, no uses un bucle. Un saludo.

Comment: Si vas a mostrar varios registros, es mejor hacer una sola consulta que te devuelva los registros a mostrar. Luego por supuesto necesitas un bucle para recorrer el conjunto de datos. Pero si realizas una consulta por cada registro, el rendimiento será peor, y, además, debes de saber de antemano algo que te permita identificar cada elemento. Así que lo mejor es coger con una consulta todos los registros (o aquellos que vas a mostrar, si aplicas algún filtro).